# Java JMS - Message Listener and onException

Tags: java, jms

I have an application with a main thread and a JMS thread which talk to each other through ActiveMQ 5.15.11. I am able to send messages just fine, however I would like a way to send back status or errors. I noticed that the `MessageListener` allows for `onSuccess()` and `onException(ex)` as two events to listen for, however I am finding that only `onSuccess()` is getting called.

Here are snippets of my code.

**JMS Thread:**

```java
ConnectionFactory factory = super.getConnectionFactory();
Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Queue queue = session.createQueue(super.getQueue());
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
consumer.setMessageListener(m -> {
   try {
      super.processRmbnConfigMsg(m);
   } catch (JMSException | IOException e) {
      LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);

      // I can only use RuntimeException. 
      // Also this exception is what I am expecting to get passed to the onException(..)
      // call in the main thread.
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
});
connection.start();
```

**Main thread (sending messages to JMS):**

```java
sendMessage(xml, new AsyncCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onException(JMSException e) {
        // I am expecting this to be that RuntimeException from the JMS thread.
        LOG.error("Error", e);
        doSomethingWithException(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        LOG.info("Success");
    }
});
```

What I am expecting is that the exceptions thrown in the `new RuntimeException(e)` will get picked up on the `onException(JMSException e)` event listener, in some way, even if the `RuntimeException` is wrapped.

Instead, I am always getting `onSuccess()` events. I suppose the `onException(..)` event happens during communication issues, but I would like a way to send back to the caller exceptions.

**How do I accomplish that goal of collecting errors in the JMS thread and sending it back to my calling thread?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expectation is based on a fundamental misunderstanding of JMS.

One of the basic tenets of brokered messaging is that producers and consumers are logically disconnected from each other. In other words...A producer sends a message to a broker and it doesn't necessarily care if it is consumed successfully or not, and it certainly won't know *who* consumes it or have any guarantee when it will be consumed. Likewise, a consumer doesn't necessarily know when or why the message was sent or who sent it. This provides great flexibility between producers and consumers. JMS adheres to this tenet of disconnected producers and consumers.

There is no *direct* way for a consumer to inform a producer about a problem with the consumption of the message it sent. That said, you *can* employ what's called a "request/response pattern" so that the consumer can provide some kind of feedback to the producer. You can find an explanation of this pattern along with example code [here](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/RequestReplyJmsExample.html).

Also, the `AsyncCallback` class you're using is not part of JMS. I believe it's [`org.apache.activemq.AsyncCallback`](https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/AsyncCallback.html) provided exclusively by ActiveMQ itself and it only provides callbacks for success or failure for the actual *send* operation (i.e. not for the consumption of the message).

Lastly, you should know that throwing a `RuntimeException` from the `onMessage` method of a `javax.jms.MessageListener` is considered a "programming error" by the JMS specification and should be avoided. Section 8.7 of the JMS 2 specification states:

> It is possible for a listener to throw a `RuntimeException`; however, this is considered a client programming error. Well behaved listeners should catch such exceptions and attempt to divert messages causing them to some form of application-specific 'unprocessable message' destination.
>   The result of a listener throwing a `RuntimeException` depends on the session's acknowledgment mode.
>
> - `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` or `DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE` - the message will be immediately redelivered. The number of times a JMS provider will redeliver the same message before giving up is provider-dependent. The JMSRedelivered message header field will be set, and the JMSXDeliveryCount message property incremented, for a message redelivered under these circumstances.
> - `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` - the next message for the listener is delivered. If a client wishes to have the previous unacknowledged message redelivered, it must manually recover the session.
> - Transacted Session - the next message for the listener is delivered. The client can either commit or roll back the session (in other words, a `RuntimeException` does not automatically rollback the session).

Comment: Thanks for this hint - I found my answer through https://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms though but it confirmed I was using the AsyncCallback wrong